# How to tell if a second-order curve goes below the $x$ axis?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, real-algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

Suppose we have a second-order curve in general form:

(1) $a_{11}x^{2}+2a_{12}xy+a_{22}y^{2}+2a_{13}x+2a_{23}y+a_{33}=0$.

I'd like to know if there is a simple condition that ensures that the curve has at least one point on on or below the $x$ axis, *i.e.* that the left-hand side of (1) is nonpositive.

In the trivial case that the curve is a parabola, the discriminant being nonnegative is just such a condition. But what happens in the general case?

Answer (score 2):

Solve for $y$ in the form $y= A(x) \pm \sqrt{B(x)}$ and estimate. More abstract versions are just variant of this.

Comment: Since my parameters are themselves complicated functions, I was hoping to avoid this...

Comment: Perhaps you should provide this --- and any other relevant information --- in the body of the question. 

Answer (score 1):

We may regard the left-hand side of the equation of thecurve as a quadratic polynomial in $x$. If $D(y)$ is its discriminant (with respect to $x$), then $D(y)\ge 0$ iff there  exists a point with the second coordinate $y$ on the curve. Solve this inequality for $y$ and check whether its minimal solution is negative:)))

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question. A point ON the $x$ axis is given by $y=0,$ so $a_{11} x^2 + 2 a_{13} x + a_{33}=0.$ That IS a parabola, and so we know what the solutions are (if any). If if the discriminant is positive, you are golden. If the discriminant is 0, pick a random value of $x$ ($0$ is easiest, but that might be the solution to your quadric), and check if $y$ is positive. If the discriminant is negative, take $x = 0$ and see what the solutions are to the resulting quadric in $y.$